# EF6 + SQL 14: The most effective way to upload large number of rows into a table

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ado.net

Using Entity Framework 6 and SQL Server 2014:

I need to upload ~200,000 rows in an XML file into a SQL Server table. Each row has 5 fields in it. The data in a row is not large, but I have a large number of rows.

In y C# application, I can parse the XML file and read its data in memory no problem. But I am concern that sending one TSQL stored procedure call per row to SQL Server is not efficient. What would be the most effective way of implementing this requirement in EF6?

If Entity Framework is not suitable for this, I can use ADO.NET directly.

Comment: If what you need to do contains extensive cleaning and transformation, consider doing it in SSIS.

Comment: @HLGEM, Adding a SSIS licence cost and deployment to the architecture for one file would be a bit of over design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could package multiple rows into a DataTable, and pass as a table valued parameter (tvp) to your stored proc. Your stored proc can perform a MERGE statement using the tvp as source, or an INSERT statement which joins to the tvp.

This works well using direct ADO.NET. From a quick google, it looks like it should also work via Entity Framework. e.g.: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/78607b/using-table-valued-parameters-in-entity-framework

Some links related to tvps:

http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html

http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-perftest-2009.html

Comment: This is fantastic. Thank you so much! Is there any guideline how big TVPs can be? I am thinking to break data into chunks, but I need to know what is the optimum size for a TVP?

Comment: I've not run into any limitations into how big a TVP can be, but i guess if they are too big you may eventually run into operating system imposed memory limits. Breaking it up into chunks is a good idea - it may also help to reduce the amount of SQL Server locking during the MERGE or INSERT. I usually make the chunk size configurable, so that it is easy to tweak after the code is implemented and tried out. If the tvp just has a guid primary key, I would default the chunk size to 5000, or something like that, but obviously there are many factors involved.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `OPENROWSET` and parse directly:

```
DECLARE @xml XML
SELECT @xml = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'D:\sample.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) x

SELECT t.c.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(100)')
FROM @xml.nodes('root/row') t(c)
GO
```

Comment: The SQL Server machine does not have access to the \\UNC\Share\File.xml. Can OPENROWSER open the file at the SqlClinet machine and send it to the SQL server?

Answer (score 0):

You can get significantly better performance out of Entity Framework by setting context.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false while you add entities and switching it on again just before calling SaveChanges. Adding entities in small batches and disposing the context each time can also help.

Alternatively there are a few of third-party libraries which do an even better job:

[EntityFramework.BulkInsert](https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/)

[Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)

[Entity Framework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/)

The latter two are commercial and I believe Entity Framework Plus is an evolution of Entity Framework Extensions.